# Unable to print out list object contents using JSTL

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, jstl

I am retrieving rows from a Mysql database and storing each row as an object in a list.
I pass the list to the request scope where I am attempting to use JSTL to loop over the list and access the object variables.

Here is how I retrieve the rows as objects:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{

        // get list of objects
        List<Game> gameRatingsThisWeek = getHighestRatedGameThisWeek();
        request.setAttribute("gameRatingsThisWeek", gameRatingsThisWeek);

        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/dashboard.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);

    private List<Game> getHighestRatedGameThisWeek() {
        List<Game> list = new ArrayList<Game>();
        try(Connection con = ds.getConnection()){
            String query =   "SELECT overallRating, count(*) as Total, g.name"
                            +"FROM gameSurvey gs, game g"
                            +"WHERE g.id = gs.gameID AND"
                            +"date BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()"
                            +"GROUP by overallRating"
                            +"ORDER by Total desc";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                Game game = new Game();
                game.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                game.setRating(rs.getInt("overallRating"));
                game.setTotal(rs.getInt("Total"));
                list.add(game);
            }
            ps.close();

        }catch(SQLException e){}
        return list;

    }

}
```

I know the SQL query is fine, because I tested it previously.

Here is the Game class:

```
public class Game {
    private int rating, total;
    private String name;

    // get
    public int getRating(){
        return rating;
    }
    public int getTotal(){
        return total;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    // set
    public void setRating(int rating){
        this.rating = rating;
    }
    public void setTotal(int total){
        this.total = total;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

In the dashboard.jsp file I attempt to loop through the list:

```
<c:forEach items="${gameRatingsThisWeek}" var="game">
    <c:out value="${game.name}"></c:out>
</c:forEach>
```

I navigating to the servlet that retrieves and forwards to the .jsp page. But nothing is output to the webpage.

Comment: Have you tested your list is not empty? Try checking just before forwarding.

Comment: How can I check this please? I'm not familiar with debugging in eclipse to see variables values.

Comment: Add a breakpoint at the start of doGet and a watch on gameRatingsThisWeek. To do this right click the variable while on debug mode and click on "Add Watch". Alternatively just so a sysout on the list (but try the debugger first).

Comment: AH I see thank you. Apparently the list is empty as you suggested. I can't see why it would be though.

Comment: Your query, which is concatenated string literals, should have spaces at the end of each line.  Without them, you have a broken SQL statement.

Comment: @Tap That was the problem thank you. Fell free to answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query is missing spaces in each of the string literals.  This means that your database is seeing the following statement:

```
SELECT overallRating, count(*) as Total, g.nameFROM gameSurvey gs, game gWHERE g.id = gs.gameID ANDdate BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()GROUP by overallRatingORDER by Total desc
```

Just add the spaces and give it another try.

```
        String query =   "SELECT overallRating, count(*) as Total, g.name "
                        +"FROM gameSurvey gs, game g "
                        +"WHERE g.id = gs.gameID AND "
                        +"date BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW() "
                        +"GROUP by overallRating "
                        +"ORDER by Total desc";
```